# Is supercalifradgilisticexpealidocious In the oxford dictionary?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

My problem is that my ‘friend’ does not think that supercalifradgealisticexpealoidociouS is a word.

Comment: You misspelled it:  supercalifragilisticexpialidocious

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-supercalifragilisticexpialidocious-a-real-word

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk02XVMrOFwlhDUKjCIoWKYl_uqVdbw%3A1585532730783&ei=Ok-BXtfAL8Ox0PEPxtyCiA0&q=supercalifragilisticexpialidocious+definition&oq=supercalifragilisticexpialidocious&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHMgQIABBHUABYAGD7ywNoAHAEeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab

Comment: What does your friend think it is if it's *not* a word? It has and established pronunciation and meaning, so...

Comment: If nothing else it is certainly a title. That should get passe the word boundary.

Comment: _Is [word-x] in [dictionary-z]?_ Why not just look in the dictionary yourself instead of asking others to do it for you?

Comment: The real question is whether [extinctionspectrophotopoleriscopeocculogravogyrokynetometer](http://www.nssa.com.au/nsfs/Membership/Member_Interests/Luke_Plaizier/spacetrivia.txt) is a "real" word.

Answer (score 1):

Is it in Lexico/New Oxford American Dictionary/etc.? [Yes.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/supercalifragilisticexpialidocious)

What about the Oxford English Dictionary (OED.com)? Also yes. The earliest example it has for the word (albeit with a slightly different spelling) is 1931, in the *Daily Orange* (Syracuse):

> I have found that this expression of mine is very adequate in any type of appreciation. When asked how you liked a certain movie,..or what your opinion is of Santa Claus, you can merely answer, ‘Supercaliflawjalisticexpialadoshus!’, and you will have condensed many thoughts into one.

The OED also points out that *Mary Poppins* wasn’t even the first time a song was thusly named, and that was even the subject of a [1965 lawsuit](https://www.casemine.com/judgement/us/59149aefadd7b0493462d0cd).